# How to pass an (OAuth) access token in an API call?

Tags: oauth-2.0

I'm struggling with an API call using OAuth 2.0 and Python.

The flow, as I understand it, should be this:

1. Request a token using a client_id (API Key) and a client_secret
2. If successful, receive an access token and refresh token.
3. Make the desired API call, using the access_token.

Now my problem is that step 3 doesn't work.

```
#requesting access token
URL='https://www.geni.com/platform/oauth/request_token?client_id=...&client_secret=......&grant_type=client_credentials'
response = requests.post(OAuthURL)
listReponse = json.loads(response.text)
print ("access_token acquired: ", listReponse['access_token'])
```

This is just fine.
With guidance from James, the token is used in the headers, not as a query parameter.

```
# so this won't work
URL = "https://www.geni.com/api/profile-122248213/immediate-family?access_token="+listReponse['access_token']
```

So

```
URL = "https://www.geni.com/api/profile-122248213/immediate-family"

theHeaders={'Content-Type':'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(theAccessToken)}
print ('Headers:', theHeaders)

>>> Headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': 'Bearer:aaaaa3LRm6frS4FwZvB3ZMZwdKVNMCEBpBvlFwbT'}
```

Produces this

```
{'error': {'type': 'OAuthException', 'message': 'Invalid access token'}}
```

yet when I validate the token using a different API endpoint for that purpose, I get

```
{"result":"OK"}
```

So best I can determine, the formatting of the headers is the problem.
What am I doing wrong?

```
theHeaders={'Content-Type':'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(theAccessToken)}
```

Comment: You've elided a lot of detail there, so I'm going to guess on what you're really doing. The Access Token needs to be a payload header, prefixed with `Bearer: `. So your followup call (step3) needs to have a `headers` element containing `{"Authorization": "Bearer " + your access token}`.

Comment: OK, that makes sense... so the acquired token must now be used in the header, not as a query parameter.

Comment: @James McPherson IF you want to make your comment, an answer, I'm happy to close this question. My learning from this are that tokens belong in the header, not the URL query parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @Maxcot for the confirmation. Following on from my initial comment about the Authorization element being a request header rather than query param, there's another niggle.

In the printed headers

```
>>> Headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': 'Bearer:aaaaa3LRm6frS4FwZvB3ZMZwdKVNMCEBpBvlFwbT'}
```

there's an error. The `Authorization` header must be formed like this:

```
Authorization: Bearer $yourBearerToken
```

so you're mostly right but have an extraneous `:`. Using your example token text, the header should be

```
Authorization: Bearer aaaaa3LRm6frS4FwZvB3ZMZwdKVNMCEBpBvlFwbT
```

If you were exporting this as a shell variable, it would be

```sh
export AUTH="Authorization: Bearer aaaaa3LRm6frS4FwZvB3ZMZwdKVNMCEBpBvlFwbT"
```

but since you're using this in Python, the headers are

```py
headers = {
    "Content-type": "application/json",
    "Authorization": "Bearer aaaaa3LRm6frS4FwZvB3ZMZwdKVNMCEBpBvlFwbT"
}
```

Comment: I'm actually new to this whole OAuth thingy, and I think I need to address some more fundamental understandings of the sequence and flows in authorizing and authenticating. So yeah, my  code quite likely has other issues,  but I will deal with them in separate, specific questions. Thanks for your help.